# App crashes when didFinishLaunchingWithOptions is called

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have an the app when notification is fired i get a notification bar when the app is in background ,when i tap on that bar it navigates into tableview of the notification set . When i quit the app from background i am receiving notification but when tap on the notification bar the app is getting crashed since its not getting indexpath of the tableview.

**When the app is quit in background and reloading the app should enter didfinishlaunching.**

In appDidFinishLaunching i am calling the method which navigates into tableview

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.viewController = [[PPViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil] ;

     UILocalNotification *notification = [launchOptions objectForKey:              UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];

    if (notification)
        {
            int remedyID = [[notification.userInfo objectForKey:kRemindMeNotificationRemedyIDKey] intValue];
            NSDictionary *reminderDetails =[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:notification.userInfo,@"kRemindMeNotificationDataKey",[NSNumber numberWithInt:remedyID],kRemindMeNotificationRemedyIDKey,nil];

            [_viewController goToReminder:reminderDetails showNotification:YES];

       }
     [application setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent];
    self.viewController = [[PPViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PPViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;

}

**This is the code which navigates into tableview in another viewcontroller**

- (void)goToReminder:(NSMutableDictionary *)reminderDictionary showNotification:(BOOL)shouldShowNotification

{
    NSIndexPath *selectedSymptIP = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:selectedSymptomIndex inSection:keyIndexNumber];

    [self tableView:symptomsTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:selectedSymptIP];

}
```

Comment: What line is the app crashing on? Do you have a crash log?

Comment: @Ric the app crashes when the app is quit in the background and when notification fires by clicking on notification bar . If the app is running in background and when notification is fired ..when bar is clicked the app navigates properly

Comment: Thanks. If you set a breakpoint at the first line of `application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` and step through the method, where does the crash happen? My guess would be that this line `int remedyID = [[notification.userInfo objectForKey:kRemindMeNotificationRemedyIDKey] intValue];` may be the problem if the userInfo is not being decoded properly.

Comment: @Ric when i quit the app how will breakpoint work cause it would have disconnected from xcode

Comment: Take a look at the way you are setting up the viewController here. At the start of the method, you are setting the property, but not setting the `rootViewController` of the `window` like you are at the bottom of the method. See if you can clean up the code a little to handle both instances similarly. Perhaps even try to simply launch the viewController when you get the notification, and then after that succeeds try to invoke the `gotoReminder:showNotification:` method.

Comment: It seems also that reminderDetails is not built correctly as you define 3 objects and 2 keys before the "nil" that terminates the list: NSDictionary *reminderDetails =[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:notification.userInfo,                                         @"kRemindMeNotificationDataKey",[NSNumber numberWithInt:remedyID],kRemindMeNotificationRemedyIDKey,@"selectedSymptIP",nil];

Comment: @viggo sorry that was my mistake i forgot to remove it ...while posting it here ...still my app is getting crashed

Comment: @raptor, post full error stack trace.

Comment: @Ravi ...I am not able to find error since this is happening when the app is quit from background and xcode doesn't have any connection to it....if u r ok.I'll send my project to u ...send me ur email

Comment: no dude, don't send me the proj because I am dead busy. How are you running your project ? Aren't you running it from xcode ?

Comment: When I fire notification ..when the app is in background the notif  fires I have developed a method when u tap on the bar app will navigate to tableview where notification switch was ON .If I do the same thing when app is quit from background the app crashes

Comment: Yes, I understand that but where are you running your project from ? isn't that from xcode ?

Comment: which is why I am telling you check your xcode log window. And post the full stack trace. It logs everything.

Comment: cool ! alright, will look into it !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem ..the crash was occurring since wrong xib file was loaded .

Answer (score 0):

When you quit the app and your app starts again, your `viewController` is not yet set up. When launching from a notification, you need to check if you are resuming from the background, or launching normally.

Look at `applicationWillEnterForeground` and `applicationDidBecomeActive` in the `UIApplicationDelegate` protocol reference for how to handle resuming your app from various states. Also see: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW3